# Why wont the even and odd numbers print true answers?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am writing a program and I want to create a list, maybe two if needed. Ten even and odd random numbers (1, 100) with the sums of each, [even] and [odd]. I have tried to do this many ways, but want to keep it as simple as possible. Im just getting a little frustrated. I will include what I have now and maybe someone can interject something that will be useful. I have just the basics now because it is confusing to see what I had prior.

```
import random


def main():
    total_odd = 0
    total_even = 0
    num_list = []

    for count in range(10):
        num = random.randint(1, 100)
        num_list.append(num)
        total_odd += num 
        total_even += num 

    print(total_odd, total_even)
    print(num_list)



main()
```

Output =

```
>>> 
485 485
[76, 76, 74, 2, 9, 30, 30, 29, 66, 93]
>>>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar I'd suggest looking into the % operator - (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) - that way you understand what these solutions are doing and how they are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> values = [76, 76, 74, 2, 9, 30, 30, 29, 66, 93]
>>> sum_odd = sum(x for x in values if x%2)
>>> sum_even = sum(values) - sum_odd
>>> print sum_odd,sum_even
131 354
```

is probably the simplest way to do it ...

Answer (score 1):

You are never checking whether the number generated by `random.randint` is odd or even. You are just adding `num` to `total_odd` and `total_even` in *both* cases. Include the check in your `for` loop:

```
for count in range(10):
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    num_list.append(num)
    if num%2 == 0: # num is even      
        total_even += num 
    else: # num is odd
        total_odd += num
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to keep generating numbers until you have enough numbers that satisfy the criteria:

```
import random


def check_even(num):
    return num % 2 == 0


def check_odd(num):
    return num % 2 != 0


def get_numbers(checker):
    num_list = []
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        num = random.randint(1, 100)
        if checker(num):
            num_list.append(num)
            count += 1
    return num_list


def main():
    even_numbers = get_numbers(check_even)
    odd_numbers = get_numbers(check_odd)
    num_list = []
    num_list.extend(even_numbers)
    num_list.extend(odd_numbers)
    print(sum(even_numbers), sum(odd_numbers))
    print(num_list)
```

Your current approach only generates 10 numbers and adds them always to `num_list`. What you want is to keep generating numbers until you have 10 even numbers and to keep generating until you have 10 odd numbers.

The code above does that by calling the `get_numbers` function with an argument called `checker`, which is the function (yes, you can pass functions as arguments) that is called to check a number.